# How do I connect a lan network to the internet through the wifi of a laptop?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have two networks in my house. The first one is downstairs and uses wifi. The second one is in my room and has three computers connected to it using ethernet cables. I have a laptop with wifi, but the two others do not.

The laptop is connected to the first network with wifi and the second with ethernet.

I do not have an ethernet cable long enough to connect the two networks together.

I want to connect the second network to the internet through my laptop and the first network. How do I do this?
(The laptop has debian.)

Comment: Try [this link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/318973/how-do-i-create-a-wifi-hotspot-sharing-wireless-internet-connection-single-adap)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirements, but on Ubuntu. I hope [this link](https://www.howtoforge.com/internet-connection-sharing-masquerading-on-linux) can bring you through the right way.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: I don't think so!

Comment: You don't think what? That the link will never 404?